# toggle button height less than 30dp text disappears Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button

I am having quite a challenge with this. If the toggle button height is less than 30dp, the text disappears.
I am wondering is this a design issue or can anyone help me with a workaround?

Comment: Have You tried custom background and/or font size for it?

Comment: sandrstar I am using a custom background actually, and if I set the largest font size, if the height is less than 30, the text will disappear..any thoughts?thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the padding to 0. Sometimes you need to override the default padding.

If that doesn't do the job you can use custom graphic instead of android default graphic. The default toggle button graphic for android is 9-patch and in this there is some build in padding you can't disable from code.

You could try to setIncludeFontPadding to false. This can be done both in code and xml.

As a last resort you have to change the textsize in order to fit inside the button.

Comment: +1 (+10 if I could) - setting padding_top/bottom to 0dp made the text appear

Comment: @DenisKniazhev You can add a bounty ;) but glad it helped, cost me tons of hours as well.